# How to redirect an URL with many parameters to a subfolder name created from the first parameter, with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

**How to redirect from:**

```
https://example.com/blog/?p=title-of-blog-post&utm_source=browser&utm_medium=rss_notification&utm_id=600215.0720246513
```

**to:**

```
https://example.com/blog/title-of-blog-post
```

**In the /blog/ folder, I have the following .htaccess file:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/\?p=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Only the first parameter is of interest.

Because of the rest of the parameters, namely: `&utm_source=browser&utm_medium=rss_notification&utm_id=600215.0720246513` , I now receive the 404 error.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/\?p=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
> ```

Your first rule already does what you require when `p` is the only URL parameter. To handle additional URL params then just remove the trailing `\s` (that matches a *space*) at the end of the *CondPattern*.

For example:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/\?p=([\w-]+) [NC]
> :
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Best wishes!